# What Charities Did Jesus Contribute To?

Tags: life-of-jesus

We know from John 12:6 that Jesus' ministry had a treasurer, and from Luke 8:3 that his ministry accepted financial contributions.

What did they spend it on? Luke 8 indicates that they sometimes donated to the poor. The disciples behavior in Mark 8:4 suggests that sometimes the ministry fed those who came to see Jesus speak. And Matthew 17:24-27 suggests that he might even have covered the taxes of some followers, although that seems unclear.

What did Jesus' ministry do with it's charity?

Comment: At least some of the money would have gone towards buying food and other expenses.

Comment: you mention specific examples of what he might've done with the money, but this question is opinion based. How much money did he/they(disciples) actually get? Did they get any money beyond what was mentioned? It isn't specified in the bible and probably isn't recorded elsewhere.

Comment: An interesting, albeit speculative, topic.  All that can be answered is in reference to the standing cultural norms among Jews in those times, and those can be used as an indirect pointer to a speculative answer (see for example the parable of the widow who offered her last two shekels into the poor box ... that's a touchstone to how the culture operated within the community at the time)

Comment: 'Why was not this ointment sold for three hundred pence, and given to the poor?' Now he said this, not because he cared for the poor; but because he was a thief, and having the purse, carried the things that were put therein. (John 12: 4-6)

Comment: To close voters: The Scriptures have the answer! (John 12:4-6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus said :

> But when thou doest alms, let not thy left hand know what thy right hand doeth: That thine alms may be in secret: and thy Father which seeth in secret himself shall reward thee openly.  [Matthew 6:3,4 KJV]

So even if one managed to get the right hand and the left hand in a room together, there could be no corroboration for neither one was cognizant of the whole story.

In answer to your question : we will never know !

Answer (score 2):

**What Charities Did Jesus Contribute To?**

Apart from the obvious that we may never know, there is one who profited from the common purse: **Judas**!

Judas was in fact the money-man for Jesus and his Apostles. The purse was certainly used to added Jesus and the Apostles with their personal needs.

> 28 Now no one at the table knew why he said this to him. 29 Some thought that, because Judas had the moneybag, Jesus was telling him, “Buy what we need for the feast,” or that he should give something to the poor. - (John 13:28-29)

But it is not inconceivable that Judas frequently stole from the common Apostle’s money box! Thus it is sure that some of the common funds went into his own pocket. Perhaps he left no for others or the poor. How much was actually left over is unknown to biblical scholars.

> According to the account in the Gospel of John, Judas carried the disciples' money bag or box (Greek: γλωσσόκομον, glōssokomon), but John's Gospel makes no mention of the thirty pieces of silver as a fee for betrayal. The evangelist comments in John 12:5–6 that Judas spoke fine words about giving money to the poor, but the reality was **"not that he cared for the poor, but [that] he was a thief, and had the money box; and he used to take what was put in it."** However, in John 13:27–30, when Judas left the gathering of Jesus and his disciples with betrayal in mind, some [of the disciples] thought that Judas might have been leaving to buy supplies or on a charitable errand. - [Judas Iscariot (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_Iscariot)

Yes, Judas was a thief. **Yet Judas Iscariot also alludes to the possibility that Jesus gave alms to the poor!**

> Then one of his disciples, Judas Iscariot, he that was about to betray him, said: 'Why was not this ointment sold for three hundred pence, and given to the poor?' Now he said this, not because he cared for the poor; but because he was a thief, and having the purse, carried the things that were put therein. [(John 12:4-6)](http://www.newadvent.org/bible/joh012.htm#vrs4)

**What Charities Did Jesus Contribute To?**

End result: **Judas’ pocket and the poor**!